# KeyError: 'user_id' when using PUT request

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, postman

Recently started working with Django REST framework. I have a user table and another table that stores some relevant data for each user. I've set up POST/GET/DELETE methods fine, but I can't get the method for perform_update working - I keep getting a KeyError at /api/sdgdata/1
'user_id' error in Postman when I attempt a put request for a user. Plz see code below:

**Models:**

```
class TestDataTwo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", related_name="testdatatwo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default="N/A")
```

**Serializers:**

```
class TestDataTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TestDataTwo
        fields = (
            "id",
            "test_name",
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # get user id from validated data:
        user_id = validated_data.pop('user_id')

        # get user:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        # set user on instance:
        instance.user = user
        instance.save()

        # continue with update method:
        super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

**Views:**

```
class TestDataTwoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TestDataTwo.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = TestDataTwoSerializer
    paginator = None

    # CREATE NEW TESTDATATWO ROW FOR USER
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    # GET ALL ENTRIES OF TESTDATATWO FOR SPECIFIC USER, EXCEPT IF SUPERUSER, THEN RETURN ALL
    def get_queryset(self):
        # if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        #     return self.queryset
        # else:
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # DELETE TESTDATATWO ID
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**Postman GET:**

[image: Get]

**Postman PUT:**

[image: PUT]

I've tried a number of variations on the perform_update method, but I am guessing I am missing a reference to the user's user_id somehow...Appreciate any help.

Comment: This is because serializer doesn't have the field `user_id` based on  `fields` in `Meta`

Comment: Hi @BrianD, I added the user_id field to the serializer, but the key error problem persists. Am I missing something in the perform_update method in the view perhaps?

**Updated Serializer:**
    class Meta:
        model = TestDataTwo
        fields = (
            "id",
            "user_id",
            "test_name",
        )

Comment: Based on your code, you want the user to be based on `request.user` right? In that case since you already pass it in `serializer.save` in `perform_update`, you don't have to process it. I'll try to write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by `validated_data.pop('user_id')`, since `user_id` was not defined as a field on the serializer nor was it passed in the request data. It seems you are aiming to save the current user as the user field of the `TestDataTwo` instance being updated.

In that case you don't need to override `update`, since saving the user based on `self.request.user` on a `TestDataTwo` instance is already done by the serializer's `save` here:

```py
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

This means that you don't have to do any processing in the serializer anymore, so it can be just:

```py
class TestDataTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestDataTwo
        fields = ("id", "test_name",)

    # No need to override update for saving self.request.user to `TestDataTwo`'s user
```

For more information on this functionality, you can have a read [**`here`**..[DRF-docs-Passing-additional-attributes-to-save]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save).

Comment: Gotcha. Deleted the overridden method and that fixed it, thank you so much.